# Is it safe to clean SLR lenses with pressurized computer dust cleaners?

Tags: cleaning

Is it safe and a good idea to clean DSLR lens using [computer dust removal](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002KKIUA), which has powerful air pressure ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've not seen this recommended for a number of reasons:

- The high-pressure air can cause dust to move from a bad place to a worse place (as opposed to being removed altogether).
- The condensation caused by the pressure drop & cooling of the compressed air causes stuff to get frosty.  This *should* be temporary, but isn't likely to help in the short run.
- You really don't want any of the liquid propellants used to create pressure in the can to stick to anything inside your camera.

Comment: Excellent. I'll go ahead and buy a lens cleaning pen. Can you please suggest one?

Comment: Here's a question that does a pretty good job handling the "how should I" part:  http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1408/269